# Intermec PR3 printer to print from android app using intermec SDK?

Tags: android, printers, intermec

I'm using Intermec android SDK to print to intermec printers:
[Intermec Printer SDK](http://hsm.force.com/publickb/articles/HSM_Article/How-to-print-from-Android-to-the-Honeywell-families-of-printers)
The problem that I faced that i can't print arabic text
i'm using Intermec PR3 model.
I have no idea, 
Please help me?

This is the code snippet:

```
            lp.setBold(true);
            lp.setDoubleWide(false);
            lp.setDoubleHigh(false);
            lp.write("بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم");
            lp.setDoubleWide(false);
            lp.setDoubleHigh(false);
            lp.newLine(2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved arabic text problem as the following by using arabicIntermec lib:

```
Arabic864 arabic864 = new Arabic864();

byte[] arabicTXT = arabic864.Convert("بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم", false);

lp.write(arabicTXT);
```

Github link: [IntermecPrinter-Arabic Text](https://github.com/Elsobkey/Intermec-Printer)

Comment: Do we need to install LinePrintService-release.apk inorder to print something? Is there any jar file available instead of installing apk?

Comment: Unfortunately, you must install this apk.
this is the only solution that i reached to it.